# На счет «три» — с кавычками или без?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужны кавычки или нет?

**Бросаем на счет "три".**

Answer (score 1):

[**Грамота**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82) утверждает, что кавычки нужны.

Вопрос № 286493
Скажите, пожалуйста, как пишется фраза: **на счет "три"** — с кавычками или без?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
**Написание в кавычках правильно.**

Я бы тоже написала «три» в кавычках, предполагая, что слово «счет» здесь можно считать родовым.
В книгах же написание различно — причем соотношение это приблизительно равное (примеры из Нацкорпуса: [на счет три](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%5B%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%20%C2%AB%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%C2%BB)).

> — **На счет три** стреляю по конечностям, — дослав патрон в патронник, сузил глаза я: — Раз...
> Гаишники оказались на редкость сообразительными и **на счет «два»** послушно раскорячились у своей легковушки... (И. Деревянко)

> **— Бросаем на счет три**, — предложил Гришка.
> — Считай, давай.
> — Раз... два...
> **На счете «два»** дед Митяй отпустил бревно, упал, зарываясь носом в мягкую землю... (Е. Худаев)

***На счет три** — закрыть глаза, заткнуть уши и пригнуть голову* (В. Хлыстов-Юнг).
[***Стреляю на счет «три»***](https://www.labirint.ru/books/265701/) — название книги (А. Байкалов).